# Matlab: Get all combination of a sequence?

Tags: matlab, cell, sequence, combinations

I have a sequence like:{1,2,3}, I want to get all combination of it like:
{{},{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}
Thank you.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html I think that is what you are looking for. Try help perms.

Comment: here is an implementation for [`powerset`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20011) on FEX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/combnk.html. I believe you need combs, not perms.

Comment: Thanks. I can put combnk in a for loop to obtain all combinations with any length.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force it:

```
a  = { 1, 2, 3 };
n  =numel(a);
nn = 2^n;
res = cell(1, nn);
for ii=1:nn,
    res{ii} = a( bitget( ii-1, n:-1:1 ) == 1 );
end
```

Comment: You should rather use [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) for this purpose, and iterate over different values of k.